# I'm getting runtime error in competition platform and not in my VSC editor

Tags: python, python-3.x, runtime-error

I'm trying to solve this problem with online judge (question given below) with the below code. It runs successfully in my VSC editor and also I got the output, but it returns a runtime error on the competition platform.

**QUESTION:**

You are given an N x N grid of squares. Each square except the top left is filled with a positive integer. You start at the top left corner with a score of 0 and move to the bottom right square by moving either right by one square or down by one square. As you move to the new square, your score becomes [S/2] + k, where S was the score at your previous square and k is the number written in the current square. In the above, [x] is the largest integer which is not greater than x. Thus, [5] is 5, and [5.5] is also 5.

Write a program to find the smallest score with which you can exit the grid.

**Constraints**
4 <= N <= 30

Number in each square <= 1000

Input Format
The first line contains a single integer N, representing the size of the grid

The next N lines, each having N space separated integers giving the numbers written on successive rows of the grid

Output
The smallest score with which you can exit the grid

Time Limit
1

**My Code:**

```
import numpy as np

n= int(input())
arr=[]

for i in range(n):
    l= list(input().split(" "))[:n]
    arr.append(l)

a= np.array(arr)

l= 0
r= 0
Value=0


while l<=n and r<=n and l+1<n and r+1<n: 
    if int(a[l+1][r])<int(a[l][r+1]):
        Value=int(Value/2)+int(a[l+1][r])
        l=l+1
    else:
        Value=int(Value/2)+int(a[l][r+1])
        r=r+1

print(int(Value/2)+int(a[n-1][n-1]))
```

**Sample Input, Output:**

Example 1

Input

Input

4

0 3 9 6

1 4 4 5

8 2 5 4

1 8 5 9

Output

12

Explanation

N=4. The set of scores are as given. The 4 X 4 scores look as follows

One possible set of moves are down, right, down, right, right, down.

The corresponding scores are 1, 4, 4, 7, 7, 12

**I am new to coding so please help me with this.**

Comment: What's the exact error message?

Comment: @ForceBru It simply shows runtime error

Comment: Without more information, I would guess that you are handling input differently than the platform is expecting